# Trying to create a title using user input in batch

Tags: batch-file, command, echo, title

Trying to title the cmd window in batch but by using user input...

```
@echo off
Title Something Smart Here
Color 07

:start
cls
set /p command=

if %command% == title goto title

:title
cls
title %command%
```

really need help, I want the user to input the command so

```
"Title" "the title here"
^^command   ^^Title
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can parse user input into a command by testing only the first word:

```
@echo off
Title Something Smart Here
Color 07

:start
cls
set /p c=

for /f %%a in ("%c%") do (
  if "%%a"=="title" goto title
goto start
)

:title
cls
%c%
```

So essentially, if the user types `title [text]` it changes the title to `[text]` and the program continues. Type anything else, and it will prompt you again.